# c++ compress byte array

Tags: c++, compression

Greetings all,

I load set of images and generate volume data.I save this volume data in a

> unsigned char *volume

array.

Now I want to save this array in a file and retrieve.But before saving I want to compress the byte array since the volume data is huge.

Any tips on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a compression library? libz for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`volume` in your example is not an array. As for compression, there are books written on the topic. For something quick and easy to use with C++, check out the [boost.iostream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library, which comes with [zlib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html#basic_zlib_compressor), [gzip](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html#basic_gzip_compressor), and [bzip2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/bzip2.html#basic_bzip2_compressor) compressors.

To offset my nitpicking, here's an example (changing to `char` because it's a lot more verbose with `unsigned char`s)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
int main()
{
    const size_t N = 1000000;
    char* volume = new char[N];
    std::fill_n(volume, N, 'a'); // 100,000 letters 'a'

    io::stream< io::array_source > source (volume, N);

    {  
      std::ofstream file("volume.bz2", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary); 
      io::filtering_streambuf<io::output> outStream; 
      outStream.push(io::bzip2_compressor()); 
      outStream.push(file); 
      io::copy(source, outStream); 
     }
    // at this point, volume.bz2 is written and closed. It is 48 bytes long
}
```

Comment: Good call on the boost library, they have lots of well maintained code. Second point though, unsigned char* is an array in C++, you don't have to declare with [] brackets, if you are using C-style allocation you can dynamically allocate an array using malloc and return it to an unsigned char*

Comment: @pstr, no, `volume` is definitely a pointer, not an array, in both C and C++.

Comment: sure, its a pointer, but I pass arrays around as pointers all the time, I almost never declare my arrays with the [] syntax since most of the time I am passing them around and using malloc to allocate them, I think the pointer syntax is cleaner (but I confess I learned C first as a physics major and so it was not in a "CS" environment, a lot was focused on just get it to work so I grew to love pointers.) I will give you the fact that since it is a pointer it doesn't have to be an array, it could be a single unsigned char, but given the question I am assuming it is a chunk of data.

Comment: actually 'volume' is a pointer of size (image-width*image-height*num-of-images)

Comment: it is a pointer with a definite size and according to the Complete C Reference by Herbert Schildt it is a pointer (grant it he also calls them dynamically allocated arrays) :), but having said that, to be exact on syntax it is a pointer to an array, not an array. Matthew Flaschen and Cubbi win, I will now sneak away embarrassed.

Comment: They're just nit-picking. We all know that you meant volume is a pointer to the start of an array of unsigned chars, like you get from new unsigned char[w*h*n]

Comment: Come on guys - the question seeks insight re compression, not pointer/array usage or terminology.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of data. If the images are already compressed (jpeg, png, etc), then it won't compress anymore.

You could use zlib http://www.zlib.net/ for uncompressed images, but I'd suggest to compress each of them with something specialized on images.

Edit:

1) Lossy compression will give much higher compression rates.

2) You mentioned that they are the same size. Are they also similar? A video codec would be the best choise in that case.

Comment: The question talks of compressing volume data generated from images (whatever that is), not compressing the images themselves.

Comment: @Tony I gave just enough information for umanga to make a decision.

Comment: i load image into QImage (QT framework) and get each pixels color in grayscale.Then store the pixel value in my 'volume' pointer.

Comment: @umanga if you're using Qt, you could compress the data using `qCompress` (this directly uses zlib). Or you could use `QImage::save(QIODevice *, ...)` to save the image to an in-memory `QBuffer` as a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a 3rd party api (as already suggested). If this is C++/CLI you can use zlib.net, but if not then you will need some other library like gzip or lzma.

Here is a link for 7-zip sdk:
http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html