# Compress array of data sent through sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, compression

We have a Server that sends some data to a client(both written using c++/MFC) using sockets
The data is getting a little too big and I'm looking for solutions to compress it.  Basically I need to compress some char Arrays

I am not very familiar with MFC. I looked at zlib but I had a hard time getting anything compiling with my VS project. I am also able to use CLI (I tried using [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and got it to work on C# but when I tried it on c++ I can't manage to get the CLI arrays to play nicely with the c++ char arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is zlib a mandatory requirement of your project ?
Otherwise, some other programs have simpler header file, which are easier to work with.
For example, this one (tested with GCC and MS's VS) :

int LZ4_compress   (char* source, char* dest, int isize);

int LZ4_uncompress (char* source, char* dest, int osize);

Source code : http://code.google.com/p/lz4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use any 3rd party compression library.
Also this question deals with a similar problem : [c++ compress byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929487/c-compress-byte-array)

What error are you getting in trying to compile zlib.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://zlib.net/

Also, there's a guy who did a wrapper around it (for convenience), might be worth checking it out:  http://www.firstobject.com/easy-zlib-c++-xml-compression.htm